# Icons in Ubuntu Dock are too small

Tags: multiple-monitors, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

After setting up my second monitor, I noticed the icons on the Ubuntu Dock where smaller than before.

[image: Launcher Screenshot]

Any fix?

Comment: It's not Unity Launcher, it's Ubuntu Dock in GNOME 3.

Answer (score 0):

I had set up Dash to Dock to show on both screens, this caused the icons to change in size. Probably caused by the screen size?

Comment: Please go back to your original question by clicking on https://askubuntu.com/posts/1212226/edit and put this information into it. You have files it under Answers, but it is not an answer to your problem.

Comment: This could be an answer. Maybe he doesn't want Dash to Dock to show on both screens anymore,

Comment: I did, but since it caused problems I just removed it lol